# boost::numeric::odeint for stiff system, what if we can not get an analytic Jacobean Matrix?

Tags: boost, odeint

I am using boost::numeric::odeint rosenbrock4 integrator. The problem is I can not get a analytic Jacobean Matrix, Is there any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a numerical scheme to compute an approximate jacobian. But this has to be implemented by yourself, or some other library. odeint does not provide this functionality.

Out of curiosity: What exactly is your system where you can't find a Jacobian? If the rhs is not differentiable, you might encounter other problems with the numerics.

Comment: Maybe some data from measurements is involved such that it is difficult to get derivatives and the Jacobian.

Comment: I think we should put an approximation method for Jacobians on our todo list. But it will take some time to implement such a method.

Comment: Also in the case of large stiff ODEs, for instance hundreds of equations, the Jacobian would be so painful to manually derive. Especially if there are complex or nonlinear expressions in some of these differential equations. I guess an approximation method would be very necessary. I really like the ODEINT, it's just not practical when I solve large stiff systems due to the difficulty to implement the Jacobian.

Comment: Try `lsoda`. Checkout my fork of it https://github.com/dilawar/libsoda . The readme has link to other implementation as well.